# DC-link capacitor selection for electric vehicle

Tags: voltage, capacitor, component-selection, ripple

I'm currently trying to build a model of a three-phase inverter to be used in electric vehicles. The selection of a film DC-link capacitor is mainly dependent on the allowed voltage ripple, which is usually between 1-10% depending on the application.

I need to choose this value for my calculations, but how does the selection between 1-10% depend on the application? What is the normal value for calculations when the application is an electric vehicle, and why?

[image]

Comment: That depends. Have you tried to simulate it with the battery ESR, cable ESR and whatever input filter exists on your inverter?

Comment: I have, but the value of capacitance is going to determine the voltage ripple that is going to remain on the DC-Link right?

Comment: Partially yes. Show your simulation?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/HkUeKWd

Comment: That’s a first order simulation, if you want to make this for real and put into production, you need to include battery ESR, capacitor ESL and ESR, and possibly a non-ideal inverter. But I digress. What did you come up with in your simulation and what load step did you use?

Comment: I must add, the objective of what I'm doing is to show that the model can be used to select capacitors. Still, electrolytic capacitors are selected based on the current ripple, while film capacitors are based on the voltage ripple that the application allows, and what I'm trying to show is how I'd calculate the capacitance needed for the film capacitor.

Comment: Yes I know, this is by no means a real life accurate model.

Comment: I came up with the ripple current for all the operating points of a drive cycle, and that allows me to select the capacitor based on the current ripple requirement

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by load step?

Comment: Ripple requirement is up to what the inverter, batteries and auxiliaries can handle, and you. A load step would be to floor it from standstill or even worse, from max acceleration to maximum regen.

Comment: I see. So what would be a good assumption to make in terms of percentage, and how would I justify my choice without adding the batteries and auxiliaries?

Comment: You can’t. Ripple is limited by external factors only. For any non-EV design, I usually start with 5 % as a baseline for max load step and continue from there.

Comment: What do you mean by continue from there? I apologize, this is my first time doing this.

Comment: Look into limiting factors, inverter, batteries, EMI. Designing an EV drivetrain is no junior task.

Comment: I'm not actually designing it - this is a student project (final year individual research)... hence why I'm so unexperienced. I wanted to make as many assumptions as possible at this stage since it's not overly important for my project, but I'm struggling to find information to reference.

Comment: Then set your inverter max ripple voltage to x, battery max ripple to y and EMI max ripple to z and write an equation for capacitance C accordingly. You have several unknown variables and thus you can’t give a numerical answer.

Comment: I have the battery max ripple and I can say the EMI wasn't considered. Would it absolutely not be possible to make an assumption on the voltage ripple percentage of the DC-Link voltage ( maybe based on a typical EV)  and calculate a capacitance that would allow for the selection of the film capacitor? I wanted to choose something like 5% and just do it for that, but I can't explain my choice obviously

Comment: If I was you tutor/teacher and you state in your report “Some random dude on the internet said 5 % and I don’t understand why but I’m sticking to it”, you would not get a good grade.

Comment: @aservil1  What would the implications for your load be of varying ripple %s? What would the cost ($, size, mass) of varying size film caps be? What tradeoffs make some sense.